# Installing Cairo terminals in Gnuplot (Ubuntu)

Tags: gnuplot

I didn't find the "cairo" terminals installed with Gnuplot downloaded from the project site: they aren't listed after `set terminal`. How do I install it? I can't find any instructions on the internet.

(For example I need to use pngcairo and cairolatex).

I'm working on Ubuntu 15.10 and Gnuplot is 5.0.1.

Edit: in `config.log` I found

> cairo-based terminals: no (requires cairo>1.2, pango>1.10)

So I suppose I must install those packages: my real question is "how"?

Comment: Did you mean when you are inside the gnuplot interpreter and you write `set term` those terminal are not listed? In the configure script it is enabled by default. (Indeed you can select `--without-cairo`). Check the configure output it should say you `cairo-based pdf and png terminals: yes`. If not you need to install some library. Add the gnuplot version.

Comment: I added the information you suggested: the problem is I don't have the needed packages.

Comment: If you want only gnuplot, not updated at the last version, you can always write `sudo apt-get install gnuplot` without compiling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the development (`-dev`) library of some packages.
Let's start with

```
sudo apt-get install  libcairo2-dev  libpango1-dev
```

maybe even `libgd-dev` ...

After run `./configure` and look at the output (eventually filter it with `./configure | grep no` ) searching for the missing libraries.

**Notes**

- With `./configure --help` you can see the options that you can enable/ disable.
- With `./configure` the script will try to configure gnuplot to be compiled.  For each package it can say you `yes` or `no` when it finds the library or not...
- The library requirements change with the option you are asking for.
- With `sudo apt-get install partial_name` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> it should show you the alternatives.
- You can even search for packages with `apt-cache search partial_name` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- You may want to install the *cosy* `aptsh`.

**Reference**

- The official site of [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)
- Official gnuplot Faq [Q 2.4 How do I get gnuplot to compile on my system?](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#x1-180002.4)
- The [gnuplot development](http://www.gnuplot.info/development/index.html) help page, jump after the *Downloading sources from the CVS repository* section.

Comment: `libpango1.0-dev` and `libgd-dev` were missing (I just didn't know that _they_ were missing). Now it works fine: 
from the log: `cairo-based pdf and png terminals: yes`
and they appear and work after `set terminal`. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, usually there are other libraries that can miss... The recipe is the same, the ingredients can differ.